# How to add a new variable to blog creation form?

Tags: buddypress, forms, variables, options

I'm trying to add a new INPUT field to the blog creation form on Buddypress. Adding the front-end element is the easy part. I'm having some hard time trying to save it.

The variable is a string, and I've added `wpmu_new_blog` a function that adds the variable as an `option` (`add_option('name','value');`).

Despite the fact I've specified `global $variable` in the function, the variable won't pass.

Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I've problems to understand your question, can you add more information?

Answer (score 1):

The [Wordpress Setting API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) should provide everything you need, it even automatically stores values IIRC. As buddypress is built on top of WordPress I assume this work for buddypress as well.